# GUI Disappearing when I add JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

Alright I'm relatively new to programming and it may be just something simple that I'm missing but the other threads related to this topic the poster didn't give adequate information relative to their issue for others to provide quality answers so I will give it a shot.

```
public BenchUI(JFrame j){
    jf = j;
    init();     
    add(mainPanel);     
    topPanelButtons();  
    selectedCustomer();     
    rentalOptions();
    clientListBox();

}
```

At this point i can point out that everything works perfectly until I add the clientListBox() method. (below)

```
public void clientListBox(){
    clientList = new JComboBox(moo);
    clientList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,30));
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    leftSide.add(clientList,gbc);
}
```

i can comment it out and get my whole GUI back working perfectly but without a JComboBox.

moo is  String [] moo = {"Fish","Goat", "Monkey"};
a dummy string just for testing purposes and initialized at the start.

So any idea why my GUI completely disappears when I place in the clientList?

If anything else is necessary I'll be watching this thread and can provide additional information.

As a side note I keep getting warnings for "Raw Types" but it works without specifiying, could I potentially run into trouble by not specifying my JComboBox?

EDIT:

ok I believe I've duplicated whatever the issue is in this code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setResizable(false);

        BenchUI bu = new BenchUI(jf);
        jf.add(bu);
    }



}



    public class BenchUI extends JPanel{

    JPanel one;
    JFrame jf;
    JComboBox<String> clientList;
    String[] moo = {"Goat", "Fish", "Donkey"};

    public BenchUI(JFrame j){
        jf = j;

        one = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        one.setBackground(Color.blue);
        one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        clientList = new JComboBox<String>(moo);
        one.add(clientList);

        add(one);
    }
}
```

with the clientList stuff commented out I get my silly little blue panel and once it is added I lose the blue panel and the combobox doesnt show up as well...betting on this is a facepalm issue at this point >.<

EDIT: to include the main class.

EDIT: took out the comment marks for the JComboBox constructor and implementer

Comment: "As a side note I keep getting warnings for "Raw Types" but it works without specifiying..." As a general rule, if you're getting warnings, and you're not sure why you're getting them or whether or not it's safe to ignore, then it is much safer to assume that it *is* something to worry about. Worst case, you learn something new about Java.

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. If you have read other threads then I'm sure you came across that advice before.

Comment: Dennis - haha makes sense, I did learn a bit about putting in the element type subsequently eliminating the warnings, I think either way it won't hurt my program because of it's simplicity

Comment: camickr - I'm not so sure how to provide the correct example. As far as I can figure it out it's just dropping a combobox in a panel and everything works perfectly up to the clientListBox() addition.

(SSCCE is a new term, had to look that up :P)

Comment: Unless you can post a SSCCE then we can't help. All you have given us is a couple of method names. We are not mind readers. We can't guess what those methods do. Again are those methods even relevant to the question. The point of a SSCCE is to start with the smallest amount of code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Agrees with @camickr -- if you want an answer quick, then your best bet is to try to come up with a viable [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: init() just initializes all of my basic panels and other variables.

Comment: init() just initializes all of my basic panels and other variables.

topPanelButtons() simply adds buttons to my top panel.

selectedCustomer() and rentalOptions() add a couple other simple panels into the leftSide panel and that all works perfectly fine so I feel like the the error is somewhere in what I've provided but I will attempt to make an SSCCE.

Comment: See edit to my answer to address edits to your question.

Comment: I appreciate the help you are giving me in improving my question and hopefully finding the solution to my problem even if it's probably really frustrating to you :P

Comment: @DarDur: your question tells us one thing: you haven't studied the tutorials yet. You really need to do so before moving forward, else you will cause yourself (and others) endless frustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted sort of sscce-like (not a real SSCCE by the way since we can't run it) code doesn't add any such as the JComboBox to the JPanel and adds no components such as the current JPanel to the JFrame.

```
public class BenchUI extends JPanel{

  JPanel one;
  JFrame jf;
  JComboBox<String> clientList;
  String[] moo = {"Goat", "Fish", "Donkey"};

  public BenchUI(JFrame j){
    jf = j;

    one = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    one.setBackground(Color.blue);
    one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

    //clientList = new JComboBox<String>(moo);
    //one.add(clientList);

    add(one);
  }
}
```

and so it makes sense that none of the components will show up on any JFrame. You will want to read the Swing tutorials on how to add components to other components (or containers) and how to create and show a JFrame. Have a look at [How to Use Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html).

---

**Edit**
Your latest code now does in fact add the BenchUI JPanel to the JFrame, but still you add no components to the BenchUI JPanel, and in fact you don't even construct your JComboBox but only create a JComboBox variable. Again, I strongly urge you to read the Swing tutorials which I've linked to above as well as the general Java tutorials.

---

**Edit 2**
Some general advice:

- If you want to add a component to a GUI you must first create the component object. You are declaring your clientList JComboBox, but you never create the object.
- Then you must add the component object to a container that eventually will be part of the hierarchy leading to a top level window such as a JFrame, JDialog, JApplet and such. You never add a clientList object to the GUI.
- You should add your components to the top level window before calling `pack()` on the top level window -- which tells all the layout managers to lay out all the components they hold.
- You should then call `setVisible(true)`. One problem with your code (other than not creating important components and not adding them to the GUI!) is that you're calling `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame way too early before adding anything to the GUI.
- Read the Swing tutorial, but especially the one on using layout managers and on adding components to a top level window.

  ---

**Edit 3**

OK, now you're creating your JComboBox, but you still are adding all components to your JFrame *after* setting it visible. Please re-check my 3rd and 4th bullets in the bullet list above.

Comment: +1 for trying to follow all the updates. Based on the code that is currently posted the problem is that `jf.setVisible(true)` needs to be done AFTER `jf.add(bu)`. You will also need to remove `jf.setResizable(false)`. This method does not work properly because you have done a pack() or a setSize() on the frame.

Comment: @camickr  I actually managed to make it work properly just by adding the pack(); at the end of the main however moving the setVisible below jf.add(bu) results in all the panels and components no longer showing up again. I'm currently working through those tutorials he posted for me but I thought that was odd.

Comment: I tested my suggestion before I added it as a comment. `managed to make it work properly just by adding the pack();` - wrong solution. The order is pack(), setVisible(true) and those statements are executed AFTER components have been added to the frame.

Comment: @DarDur: see **Edit 3** to answer.

Comment: I understand why and all now but for some reason setVisible being after pack() is causing the frame to pop up with no components in it again. I'll keep working through these tutorials to see if I can find the answer

Comment: oh i think I understand why that's happening now. I believe (not sure) that my calls that reference the JFrame to get it's size are seeing zeros until it's set to visible.